# Would I be able to compile external libraries (opencv, mlpack) onto an MCU?

Tags: c++, opencv, mlpack, tinyml

I am trying to run Logistic Regression on a MCU (anything similar to [this board](http://www.ti.com/tool/LAUNCHXL-CC2650)), and I would like to run C++ and compile my program with external libraries such as [mlpack](http://mlpack.org/download.html) and opencv, would it be feasible to do that or do these boards have restrictions on what libraries it supports?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not going to happen.

The CC2650 is a microcontroller with under 32 KB of RAM. It's not going to run any kind of machine learning or computer vision algorithms -- there's barely enough memory on the part to even load an image, let alone to do anything with it.